# iAd doesn't appear when the application is approved

Tags: app-store, iad, adbannerview, revenue

Apple have just approved my Application, but the problem is the Application that not shows the banner.

I have implemented these 3 methods of delegate of the ADBannerView:

```
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner

-(BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
```

In my iPhone the banner test work perfectly and it's visible.

[image]

Did you know what's the problem?

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

Ads take time to load. The ads in my game came after one day of the app being on the app store. Just wait a little. If they still not come after a week or so, then you should contact apple.